# MySQL league table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database, as seen below:

Below is the team-tabel:

```
id  tname          poule
1   ZF Eger        heren1A
2   Pro Recco      heren1A
3   Sintez Kazan   heren1A
4   Szolnoki VSE   heren1A
5   Sintez Kazan 2 heren1B
6   Szolnoki VSE 2 heren1B
```

And below is the game-tabel:

```
id date                hteam ateam hscore ascore gamefield poule   played
 1 2008-01-01 20:00:00     1     2      0      0 Veld 1    heren1A      0
 2 2008-01-01 20:00:00     3     4     10      8 Veld 2    heren1A      1
```

The code below does an sql-query on the database and outputs the league standings.

```
SELECT  poule AS Poule, 
        tname AS Team, 
        Sum(WG) AS WG,
        Sum(W) AS W,
        Sum(G) AS G,
        Sum(V) AS V, 
        SUM(DV) as DV,
        SUM(DT) AS DT,
        SUM(S) AS S,
        SUM(P) AS P 
FROM    ( 
            SELECT  hteam 
                    Team, 
                    IF(played = 1,1,0) WG, 
                    IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) W, 
                    IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) G, 
                    IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) V, 
                    hscore DV, 
                    ascore DT, 
                    hscore-ascore S, 
                    CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END P 
            FROM games 
            WHERE   played = 1 
                AND poule = ? OR played = 1 
                AND poule = ? 

            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  ateam, 
                    1, 
                    IF(hscore < ascore,1,0), 
                    IF(hscore = ascore,1,0), 
                    IF(hscore > ascore,1,0), 
                    ascore, 
                    hscore, 
                    ascore-hscore S, 
                    CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
            FROM games 
            WHERE   played = 1 
                AND poule = ? OR played = 1 
                AND poule = ?
            ) AS tot 
        JOIN teams t 
            ON tot.Team=t.id 
GROUP BY Team 
ORDER BY SUM(P) DESC, s DESC
```

**The problem i have is:**

The teams without played matches aren't selected, but i still want them to be selected cause i need to show the complete poule, even if no matches are played. How can I change my query so that the league standings are also shown when no match has been played?

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Without a rewrite, that would be a RIGHT JOIN, but I agree a rewrite and a LEFT JOIN would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `team` as anchor and `LEFT JOIN` with your stats:

```
SELECT  
    t.poule,
    t.tname AS Team,  
    IFNULL(Sum(WG), 0) AS WG,
    IFNULL(Sum(W) , 0) AS W,
    IFNULL(Sum(G) , 0) AS G,
    IFNULL(Sum(V) , 0) AS V, 
    IFNULL(SUM(DV), 0) as DV,
    IFNULL(SUM(DT), 0) AS DT,
    IFNULL(SUM(S) , 0) AS S,
    IFNULL(SUM(P) , 0) AS P 
FROM    teams t
        LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT  hteam 
                    Team, 
                    IF(played = 1,1,0) WG, 
                    IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) W, 
                    IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) G, 
                    IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) V, 
                    hscore DV, 
                    ascore DT, 
                    hscore-ascore S, 
                    CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END P 
            FROM games 
            WHERE   played = 1 
                AND poule = ? OR played = 1 
                AND poule = ? 

            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  ateam, 
                    1, 
                    IF(hscore < ascore,1,0), 
                    IF(hscore = ascore,1,0), 
                    IF(hscore > ascore,1,0), 
                    ascore, 
                    hscore, 
                    ascore-hscore S, 
                    CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
            FROM games 
            WHERE   played = 1 
                AND poule = ? OR played = 1 
                AND poule = ?
            ) AS tot ON tot.Team=t.id 

GROUP BY t.poule,t.tname 
ORDER BY SUM(P) DESC, s DESC
```

This way, all teams are returned, including the ones that dont have stats.

**RESULTS***

```
heren1A Sintez Kazan    1   1   0   0   10  8   2   3
heren1A Szolnoki VSE    1   0   0   1   8   10  -2  0
heren1A ZF Eger         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
heren1A Pro Recco       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
heren1B Sintez Kazan 2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
heren1B Szolnoki VSE 2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: With this query it only selects the first one from my team-tabel. So if no matches have been played, then the first id is only selected.

Comment: i edited the query a bit as the grouping was not entirely right - the query should not return the results i`ve added above (i didn't filter on any league) - does that fixes the problem for you or is something else ?

Comment: that's it! Haven't got the much needed SQL experience yet, but learning fast now :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL `JOIN`s are `INNER JOIN`s. You need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    poule AS Poule, 
    tname AS Team, 
    Sum(WG) AS WG, 
    Sum(W) AS W, 
    Sum(G) AS G, 
    Sum(V) AS V, 
    SUM(DV) as DV, 
    SUM(DT) AS DT, 
    SUM(S) AS S, 
    SUM(P) AS P 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            hteam Team, 
            IF(played = 1, 1, 0) WG, 
            IF(hscore > ascore, 1, 0) W, 
            IF(hscore = ascore, 1, 0) G, 
            IF(hscore < ascore, 1, 0) V, 
            hscore DV, 
            ascore DT, 
            hscore - ascore S, 
            CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END P 
        FROM 
            games 
        WHERE 
            played = 1 
            AND poule = ? 
            OR played = 1 
            AND poule = ? 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            ateam, 
            1, 
            IF(hscore < ascore, 1, 0), 
            IF(hscore = ascore, 1, 0), 
            IF(hscore > ascore, 1, 0), 
            ascore, 
            hscore, 
            ascore - hscore S, 
            CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        FROM 
            games 
        WHERE 
            played = 1 
            AND poule = ? 
            OR played = 1 
            AND poule = ?
    ) as tot 
    LEFT JOIN teams t ON tot.Team = t.id 
GROUP BY 
    Team 
ORDER BY 
    SUM(P) DESC, 
    s DESC
```

Comment: I am confused, what you mean by this statement *By default, MySQL JOINs are INNER JOINs.*??? In every DBMS `JOIN` means `INNER JOIN` unless otherwise you explicitly specify to use `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Praveen, even if you change the query to use `LEFT JOIN` like above, it wont make a difference if you dont use `teams` table as anchor table (to the left of `LEFT JOIN`.